# How to use multiple lines in .OrderBy in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
folderList = (List<SPFolder>)folderList.OrderBy(folder => Object x = folder.GetProperty("Order Folder By"); x == null ? 0 : (int)x;).ToList();
```

But it's giving me a syntax error.

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything.  You need to return the value in a statement lambda.  You also need to wrap the statements in curly braces to use multiple statements in a lambda.  You also can't treat a conditional operator as an expression; it needs to be a statement.

They're fixed with the same fix.

```
folderList = (List<SPFolder>)folderList.OrderBy(folder => {
    Object x = folder.GetProperty("OrderFolderBy"); 
    return x == null ? 0 : x;}).ToList();
```

That said, you can do the whole thing with just an expression instead; there's no need to use multiple statements:

```
folderList = folderList.OrderBy(folder => folder.GetProperty("OrderFolderBy") as int?).ToList();
```

There also no reason for that cast.  The list should already be of the appropriate type, and both `null` and `0` come before other numbers, so there's no real reason for the null check at all.

Comment: But I need to cast `folder.GetProperty("OrderFolderBy")` to int. Right now, it could be a null or a object type.

Comment: Now it says `The operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and int`.

Comment: So i'd have to use your first example, and ignore the second?

Answer (score 2):

You need the braces since you had two statements in the lambda and you also need the cast to `object` for the `? :` operator

```
folderList = folderList.OrderBy(
    folder => 
    {
        Object x = folder.GetProperty("OrderFolderBy"); 
        return x == null ? (object)0 : x;
    }).Cast<SPFolder>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using the intermediate assignment to `x` by using the null coalescing operator `??`.

```
folderList = folderList.OrderBy(
    folder => folder.GetProperty("OrderFolderBy") ?? (object)0)
    .ToList();
```